# Android Spinner Style Not Changing

Tags: android, styles, spinner

Hey guys I'm trying to change my `Spinner` style.

I'm tried all kinds of changes to my style.xml but still nothing works,

I ended up setting the file like this:

I have this in my style.xml:

```
<style name="SpinnerTheme" parent="@android:Theme.Light">
      <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/Widget.Spinner</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.Spinner" parent="android:Widget">
     <item name="android:background">@drawable/my_rectangle</item>
     <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
</style>
```

my_rectangle looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/slim_spinner_normal" />
    <item
        android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/slim_spinner_normal" />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/slim_spinner_normal" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/slim_spinner_normal" />
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/slim_spinner_normal" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/slim_spinner_normal" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/slim_spinner_normal" />
</selector>
```

I set all the images to the same one just for the testing of it,
I can't figure out what am i missing...

Do I need to set something in my Manifest?

What am I doing wrong here?!

The `Spinner` stays the same without any changes...

Any help guys?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, Solved it.

i went through this tutorial and found it perfect!

http://www.gersic.com/blog.php?id=57

hope it helps.

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. The link is not 404 and the answer won't help anybody..